# What does =*> mean with regards to context free grammars?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I've been reading a couple books/online references about compiler theory, and keep seeing that particular operator coming up every once in a while (as seen [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/b/3/2b36fd7b9ed49a6ac3d694c5ed146fbb.png)), specifically when the current topic is context free grammars. What does it mean? As well, how does it differ from `=>`?

Explanations with examples distinguishing `=>` from `=*>` would be most helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

=> means derives in one step while =*> derives in zero or more steps (the [reflexive transitive closure of =>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_semantics_of_grammars)).

Comment: Oh - that makes sense! Actually, could you clarify how something could be derived in 0 steps?

Comment: In other words, the `*` modifies `=>` in the same way it modifies items in regular expressions.

Comment: @incrediman: It's when something derives itself. e.g. 01b =*> 01b (zero steps) vs. 01b =*> 011 (one step)